# Shabat times algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Does someone knows of an open source algorithm for calculating the times of Shabat candle light by a GPS location?

I've found this site: [hebcal](http://www.hebcal.com/home/195/jewish-calendar-rest-api)
that have a rest api but it doesn't support a gps.
they directed me [here](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/SunApprox.php)
but its not very understandable.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: These people do it: http://www.chabad.org/calendar/location_cdo/aid/6226/jewish/Candle-Lighting-Times.htm click "show co-ordinates"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The times to light and extinguish Shabbat candles are based on local sunset. So what you really need is a way to [compute the sunset time](http://williams.best.vwh.net/sunrise_sunset_algorithm.htm) for any location on a particular date.

As I understand it, candles are lighted 18 minutes before local sunset. So once you compute the sunset time, just subtract 18 minutes and you're there.

Comment: Your answer would be correct, however, the starting time for Shabbat is the ***visible sunset***, as apposed to the actual sunset. As a result of refraction and location, the two calculations vary in difference.